# How to use custom font weight value in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I want to create a Text in my SwiftUI view with a custom font weight value. How can I do that?

```
Text("TEXT")
.fontWeight(.bold)
```

This is not bold enough in my case.
I don't use a specific font family, just the default one.

Answer (score 1):

In SwiftUI use `.fontWeight()` with the other provided values, e.g. .heavy or .black

```
.fontWeight(.black)
```

UIKit's `UIFont.Weight` does have a numeric initialiser – but SwiftUI's `Font.Weight`sadly has not. So you might have to change to a `UIViewRepresentable`.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, World!")
                .font(.system(size: 24, weight: Font.Weight.black))
            
            TextWithWeight(text: "Hello World!", size: 24, weight: 0.3)
            TextWithWeight(text: "Hello World!", size: 24, weight: 0.5)
            TextWithWeight(text: "Hello World!", size: 24, weight: 0.7)
        }
    }
}


struct TextWithWeight: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let text: String
    let size: CGFloat
    let weight: CGFloat
    
    typealias UIViewType = UITextView
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let view = UITextView()
        view.text = text
        view.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: size, weight: UIFont.Weight.init(weight))
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
    }
    
    @MainActor func sizeThatFits(_ proposal: ProposedViewSize, uiView: UITextView, context: Context) -> CGSize? {
        return uiView.sizeThatFits(proposal.replacingUnspecifiedDimensions())
    }
    
}
```

Comment: That does not answer my question. I want to use a specific value for the font weight.

Comment: UIKit's `UIFont.Weight` does have a numeric initialiser – but SwiftUI's `Font.Weight`sadly has not. So you might have to change to a `UIViewRepresentable`. See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Font` using a `UIFont`. So this lets you pass a weight value when fetching the font:

```swift
private func uiFontWithSizeAndWeight(size: CGFloat, weight: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
    UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: size, weight: .init(weight))
}

var body: some View {
    Text("The quick brown fox")
        .font(Font(uiFontWithSizeAndWeight(size: 30, weight: 1.0)))
    Text("jumps over the lazy dog")
        .font(Font(uiFontWithSizeAndWeight(size: 24, weight: 0.2)))
}
```

[image: Font]

However, the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/weight) says:

> When providing a weight that doesn’t precisely match a font face in the family, the system locates a face that most closely matches the request.

So you might just as well use `.fontWeight(.black)`.